# Change JButton text and functionality depending on a specific situation

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

Basically what I am searching for is how to make a button's text and functionality change dynamically depending on the situation. For example I am working on a card game where I save selected cards of the user into an array, and I want it so when 1 or more card is selected, the button's name should be Play, and have the player to play that move, while if 0 cards are selected, the button's name should be Pass so on click the user can pass the turn. The button's text should change itself only depending on the number of selected cards, and not on click etc. 
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2Idx.png)

Comment: Sounds like you need some kind of state manager, which can generate notifications based on the current state, to which observers can change their own state accordingly

Comment: Don't use `ActionListener`. Use [Action](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could create two separate buttons where each has its own ActionListener and change which buttons are visible depending on the situation:

```
JButton pass_button = new JButton("Pass");
JButton play_button = new JButton("Play");

// Loop this code on separate thread or use callback
if(num_cards_selected == 0 && panel.contains(play_button)) {
    panel.remove(play_button);
    panel.add(pass_button);
} else if(num_cards_selected > 0 && panel.contains(pass_button)) {
    panel.remove(pass_button);
    panel.add(play_button);
}
```

Or you could check the state of the card game and have an ActionListener that is tied to the JButton act according to the condition:

```
JButton button = new JButton("");

// Loop this code on separate thread or use callback
if(num_cards_selected == 0)
    button.setText("Pass");
else
    button.setText("Play");

button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(num_cards_selected == 0)
            pass();
        else
            play();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The functionality part is easy, you just add action listener to the button as usual, but do something different depend on the number of selected cards.

As for the button text, you should have a method like updateButtonText() which assign different text to the button based on currently selected cards. And you call this method at start to assign the initial text.

Then whenever you detected user has change in card selection, you simply call updateButtonText() again to have the button text updated.

Answer (score 0):

**What you need is :**

- check the number of cards selected
- add [action listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) to button and change the outcome of the action as per the cards selection

**Code example :**
check all the comments provided in the code

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class cardGame implements ActionListener {
    int cards[];
    JButton b1;
    JFrame f;
    JPanel panel;

    public cardGame(int n) { // taking input n as how many cards have been
                                // selected
        cards = new int[n]; // number of cards selected

        f = new JFrame(); // creating a jFrame
        f.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400)); // size of JFrame

        panel = new JPanel(); // creating a panel

        b1 = new JButton("click"); // creating a JButton
        b1.setSize(20, 30); // setting size of JButton
        b1.addActionListener(this); // adding action listener

        panel.add(b1); // adding JButton to panel

        f.add(panel); // adding panel to JFrame
        f.pack();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // setting default
                                                            // close operation
        f.setVisible(true); // set JFrame visible

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (cards.length >= 3) { // if cards are more than or equal to 3
                                    // setBackground color blue

            b1.setText("Play");
            panel.setBackground(Color.blue);

        }
        // you can change the functionality as per your need
        else {// else setBackground color green
            b1.setVisible(true);
            b1.setText("pass");
            panel.setBackground(Color.green);

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new cardGame(2); // providing input as number of cards selected try
                            // giving 2 and 3
    }

}
```